# Single sign on issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have done single sign on settings between dev (Identity provider) and  dev3 (service provider).

Change dev3 app to service  or any apps

•   Click on Ecmc repository  link on dev ,it will take  you to dev3 but landing App is service (or any apps).

```
<a class="slds-tabs" onclick="{!c.EcmsRepository}">ECMS Repository</a><br/>
```

Js:

```
   EcmsRepository:function(component, event, helper){
   window.open('https://vmware-gs--dev.cs78.my.salesforce.com/idp/login? 
   app=0sp1k000000Caic&sfdc.tabName=01r0n000000DGpI&tsid=02u0n000000CwjT');
}
```

For fixing landing app issue, I have added below line of code.

```
   window.open('https://vmware--dev3.my.salesforce.com/apex/AptsAgmtHome?sfdc.tabName=01r0n000000DGpI&tsid=02u0n000000CwjT');
```

Updated Js code:

```
               EcmsRepository:function(component, event, helper){
        window.open('https://vmware--dev3.my.salesforce.com/apex/AptsAgmtHome? 
  sfdc.tabName=01r0n000000DGpI&tsid=02u0n000000CwjT');
   window.open('https://vmware-gs--dev.cs78.my.salesforce.com/idp/login?app=0sp1k000000Caic&sfdc.tabName=01r0n000000DGpI&tsid=02u0n000000CwjT');
}
```

This code will work fine  in the same session. It will fix landing page issue also.

**

> But It will fail in this scenario of testing, If we logout from dev
>   (close dev from browser and reopen) and again click on ecmc repository
>   link. it  asks user name and password for dev3.

**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open perticular Apps in another org after clicking button in Lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256699/how-to-open-perticular-apps-in-another-org-after-clicking-button-in-lightning-co)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tsid  url hacking.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231914&language=en_US&type=1)

To use `tsid` hack you need to find the appId, which you can get it from setup->app->your app.

```
<a class="slds-tabs" onclick="{!c.EcmsRepository}">ECMS Repository</a><br/>


  EcmsRepository:function(component, event, helper){

    window.open('https://vmware-gs--dev.cs78.my.salesforce.com/idp/login?tsid=02u58000000MjMx');
}
```